# Erro "java.lang.NullPointerException" em Java

Tags: java, classes

Boa tarde, estou com um erro na linha 17 da main. Tenho um objeto "Aluno" e outro objeto "POO1". Escrevi o seguinte código:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno ();
Avaliacao poo1 = aluno.getAvaliacao();
```

Para enviar as notas escrevi isso:
    //Na main
    aluno.setAvaliacao(2.3, 3.1, 5.2, 1.1);

```
//Na classe Aluno
public void setAvaliacao(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    Avaliacao x = new Avaliacao (a, b, c, d);
    avaliacao = x;
}
```

E o construtor de Avaliação:

```
 public Avaliacao(double nota1, double nota2, double exercicioAula, double trabalhofinal) {
    this.nota1 = nota1;
    this.nota2 = nota2;
    this.exercicioAula = exercicioAula;
    this.trabalhoFinal = trabalhofinal;
}
```

O get para as notas ficou dessa forma:

```
public Avaliacao getAvaliacao() {
    return avaliacao;
}
```

E o atributo

```
private Avaliacao avaliacao;
```

A minha dúvida é por que está aparecendo o erro quando vou printar qualquer nota na main? Segue como fiz a lógica para mostrar alguma nota enviada:

```
System.out.println("Nota 1: " + poo1.getTrabalhoFinal()); //Aqui aparece erro
//Erro: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Em caso de dúvidas, segue a classe Aluno:

```
public class Aluno {
private String nome;
private String matricula;
private Avaliacao avaliacao;

public Aluno() {
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public Avaliacao getAvaliacao() {
    return avaliacao;
}

public void setAvaliacao(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    Avaliacao x = new Avaliacao (a, b, c, d);
    avaliacao = x;
}
}
```

Segue a classe Avaliacao:

```
public class Avaliacao {
private double nota1;
private double nota2;
private double exercicioAula;
private double trabalhoFinal;

public Avaliacao(double nota1, double nota2, double exercicioAula, double trabalhofinal) {
    this.nota1 = nota1;
    this.nota2 = nota2;
    this.exercicioAula = exercicioAula;
    this.trabalhoFinal = trabalhofinal;
}

public double getNota1() {
    return nota1;
}

public void setNota1(double nota1) {
    this.nota1 = nota1;
}

public double getNota2() {
    return nota2;
}

public void setNota2(double nota2) {
    this.nota2 = nota2;
}

public double getExercicioAula() {
    return exercicioAula;
}

public void setExercicioAula(double exercicioAula) {
    this.exercicioAula = exercicioAula;
}

public double getTrabalhoFinal() {
    return trabalhoFinal;
}

public void setTrabalhoFinal(double trabalhoFinal) {
    this.trabalhoFinal = trabalhoFinal;
}
}
```

Comment: Acho que o problema está acontecendo porque você não chamou o método `setAvaliacao` antes de chamar o `getAvaliacao`

Comment: e sua classe main?

Comment: O erro foi exatamente esse, o set estava depois do get, eu estava pensando de outra forma. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo, vou testar aqui. Meu professor fez dessa forma em aula.

Comment: Como posso deixar o set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não está sequer a mostrar o que faz o método getTrabalhoFinal(). Para estar a dar esse erro é porque não estão a ser criadas as instâncias que quer mostrar, isto é, os valores retornados pelo método getTrabalhoFinal() estão a null. É uma questão de rever este caso ou mostrar todas as classes que influenciem o fluxo de código para este caso para que seja possível uma melhor ajuda.

Para criar as instâncias teria de fazer algo do género, por exemplo:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno ();
aluno.setAvalicao(18,17,12,9);
```

Comment: Entendi meu erro, muito obrigado!

Comment: Não quer dar aí o upvote? eheh

Answer (score 1):

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno ();
//Falta setar as notas do aluno
aluno.setAvalicao(...)
Avaliacao poo1 = aluno.getAvaliacao();
```